# CSS sticky navbar issue

Tags: html, css, navbar, sticky

navbar disappears in second section. tried everything but does not work. I am not into coding btw. just complying to a subject requirement  [here is the file to get a better look](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Qx0Hd-RHADCoYrthceVFuR7gMuWcl0x/view?usp=sharing)

tried everything I understand at my level. it is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

In your style.css make these changes:

```
.navbar {
     z-index: 10;
}

#about{
     z-index: 5;
}
```

### What does that mean?

The value of **z-index** is **more** in navbar than in about section. **More z-index value will give it more priority and it will be positioned on the top.**

Read more about z-index at https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_z-index.asp

Comment: If this works, feel free to accept the answer so that it could help others as well!

Answer (score 0):

the first - you should handle images or gift or video size and convert to for web types because
your web site very big size and delay for loading ,

the second - Adding this might solve your problem

```
.navbar {
   z-index: 9999
}
```